# duplicating all objects even child objects

Tags: modeling

Is there a way to duplicate all child objects when I duplicate the parent object. I know I can't just click the parent object and shift+d and expect the child objects also duplicate with it. What are some of yalls tricks?

Comment: I would do just like mqbaka mqbaka. However that I have to "select Hierarchy is a bug (not really a bug but a feature) in blender that really annoys me. Just selecting the parent should work fine. Hope they change that in the future...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to select all the objects you want to duplicate.**

I don't know of any way that allows to duplicate an object without selecting it (unless you want to consider coding).

If you want to also duplicate the parents along with all it's children you can go to the outliner and right click on the parent and `Select Hierarchy` :

[image: Select hierarchy]

Then duplicate them with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>.

If you want to duplicate only the children and not the parent, you can select the parent and press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>>`Children` (or `Immediate Children` if you want to only select direct children):

[image]

This will deselect the parent and select only the children.

Alternatively, you can select one of the children and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>>`Siblings` but keep in mind that this only selects those that are on the same level of hierarchy as the active one i.e. it will not select the children of the children.